# Update one form based on selections from another form

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, combobox

I apologise if the title is a bit vague, i've only been on here a day.

So my problem is I have a menu form in which I input the options from the comboboxes. And then I go to the next form which shows the relevant imported text file info.
However when I click the 'back' button to return to the menu and input different information in the comboboxes, it doesn't take me to the correct text file info, it just shows the info from the previous selection.

[here is the student menu pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5hd1.png)

[here is the text file form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/695cc.png)

below is the code for the student menu next button:

```
    If OptionBox.Text = "Introduction" Then

        Introduction.Show()

    Else
        If OptionBox.Text = "Explanation" Then
            Explanation.Show()
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

below is the code for the text file form load page and the back button

```
Private Sub Introduction_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Student_Menu.Hide()

    Dim font As New System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 11)

    If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Computer Systems" Then

        Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\ComputerSystems.txt"
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
        IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()

        sr.Close()
    Else
        If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Hardware" Then
            Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\Hardware.txt"
            Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
            IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()

            sr.Close()
        Else
            If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Software" Then
                Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\Software.txt"
                Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
                IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
            Else
                If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Representation of Data" Then
                    Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\RepresentationOfData.txt"
                    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
                    IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                Else
                    If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Databases" Then
                        Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\Databases.txt"
                        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
                        IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    Else
                        If Student_Menu.TopicSelect.Text = "Communications & Networks" Then
                            Dim strFile As String = "C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gcsecomputingtask\textfiles\Introduction\Hardware.txt"
                            Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)
                            IntroductionLabel.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    IntroductionLabel.Font = font


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Me.Hide()

    Student_Menu.Show()

    Student_Menu.TopicSelect.ResetText()
    Student_Menu.OptionBox.ResetText()


End Sub
```

what do i need to do in order to update this information so that the program doesn't skip going through the form again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of repeated code there.  Here is a way to reduce it (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and expose a method to change the topic.   In a Module:

```
Public Enum Topics
    ComputerSystems
    Hardware
    Software
    Data
    Database
    Networks
End Enum
```

Then in the form that shows the text:

```
Friend Sub DisplayTopic(topic As Topics)
    Dim text As String
    Dim filname As String = ""

    Select Case topic
        Case Topics.ComputerSystems
            filname = "ComputerSystems.txt"
        Case Topics.Database
            filname = "Databases.txt"
            '... etc
    End Select

    ' attach path
    filname = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                         "gcsecomputingtask", filname)

    text = File.ReadAllText(filname)
    IntroductionLabel.Text = text
End Sub
```

By the way, VB does has an `ElseIf` which can avoid the ["arrow" anti pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern) you can see in your code.  At the very least, the excessive indentation is annoying.

```
    If topic = Topics.ComputerSystems Then
        '...
    ElseIf topic = Topics.Software Then
        '...
    End If
```

Show that form normally using an instance of the form class:

```
Public Class MenuForm    ' a form is just a class
    ' declare an object variable to use
    Private info As Form2     ' whatever its name is (Explanation???)
    ....
    Private Sub MenuForm_Load(...)
       ' create an instance to be used later:
       info = New Form2
```

Then invoke the method to tell it which topic to display.  Displaying topic info is a separate method from loading a form first because the form load event happens only once.  A specialized method to do what we want makes more sense since they really have nothing to do with one another, and makes it easier to see how the code works:

```
info.DisplayTopic(Topics.ComputerSystems)
info.Show
```

This way, you dont have one form fiddling with the controls on another, but still have a clear way of communicating which topic to display.

Note that the location of the topics file(s) is a bit different.  You'd want a "gcsecomputingtask" folder in `MyDocuments` for the files.  The VS project folder is not a good place for it, the folder location could change depending on which machine you are running on (yours or computer lab etc).  They could also be stored as a resource to skip that part too.

Comment: Since there are many ways the user could exit the form,  once you do `info.Show()` the home/main/picker form could reset the select itself.  Just ignore changes to the CBO when `SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: ok so now I have created a new module for the topics, i have put the DisplayTopic sub in the Introduction form where the text is shown. I put the private info as new Introduction and put the info.displaytopic - but how do I end that private info, is it supposed to be private sub info.

Comment: there is no `private sub info` in my code.  I was showing the correct way to use a form using instances.  Just put `Private info As New Form???` (use your form name) at the top of the menu form.  I guess your class name is `Explanation` but that is a ***class*** you should create an instance of it to show (`info` in my answer)

Comment: I expanded that part of the answer...are they not teaching to create form instances at your school?

Comment: I have added Private info As New Introduction in my student menu form below the public class bit now. when i put in the Public Sub DisplayTopic(ByVal topic As Topics), i put it under the public class for the introduction form and theres an error saying  'topic' cannot expose type 'Module1.Topics' outside the project through class 'Introduction'.

Comment: Not really a lot of what i do is self taught

Comment: I was trying to avoid a problem with scope and got confused. Make the module public: `Public Module Module1` or better, make it `Friend Sub DisplayTopic()` (as shown now)  I cant be certian that you havent gotten your forms mixed up.  The main/menu form gets the form reference to the other form which shows the text/explanation gets the Friend method (you call it different things in the Q - "text file form").  So that Menu form can pass the selection to the form that displays the text.

Comment: I changed the module to be public and I realised I added the displaytopics in the wrong part of the code. Its working now which is great! hopefully it'll stay that way. Thank you so much you're literally my saviour aha